# SonarQube Rules Conflict

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube reported 'Make "ids"  transient or serializable' for this line of code:

```
private final List<String> ids;
```

So I changed it to:

```
private final ArrayList<String> ids;
```

and made sure that my public interface (the constructor in this case) still used just an interface:

```
public MyClass(List<String> ids) {
    this.ids = (ids == null) ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(ids);
}
```

This got rid of the first SonarQube warning, but now it gives:

The type of the "ids" object should be an interface such as "List" rather than the implementation "ArrayList".

I don't want to turn off all rules for using interfaces rather than concrete classes, but only for cases like this.

Comment: Can you precise the version of the sonar-java plugin you are using ? You are describing this ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of the Java plugin you're using, but it's likely pre-3.4; [that rule was relaxed](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-808) in v3.4 to ignore private fields.

Comment: OK. I just updated from the 3.0 plugin to the latest - 3.5. The issue still occurs. I'm also wondering why the install (which I just did this week) didn't come with the latest plugin. 

Overall the tool is wonderful, but the documentation is not very helpful and out-of-date.

Comment: A particular version of the server ships with the version of the java plugin available at that point : this means that if you use LTS version you might end up with a (slighlty) outdated plugin (but which you can upgrade quite easily through update center). 

If you found out some outdated documentation, you are more than welcome to point out what is obsolete through the sonarqube google groups. 

Finally : What do you mean exactly by "The issue still occurs" ? Do you still have the issue on the `ids` field about serialization ?

Comment: OK. It is now fixed. Just upgrading the plugin and restarting SonarQube did not fix the issue. A new build had to kick off first.